# how to map over a function with multiple arguments in python

Tags: python, list, iterator, list-comprehension

I'm looking to map over a function with lists for specific arguments.

```
def add(x, y):
    return(x + y)

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [3, 4, 5]
```

After some research I have been able to successfully do it using `map` and a `lambda` function.

```
list(map(lambda x, y: add(x, y), list1, list2))
```

I was wondering, is it better to do this using an iterator? I tried the following but couldn't figure it out:

```
[add(x, y), for x, y in list1, list2]
```

or

```
[add(x, y), for x in list1 for y in list2]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `zip` for a list comprehsion

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is *no* need to use a lambda expression here, you can pass a reference to te function directly:

```
list(map(add, list1, list2))
```

In case you want to use *list comprehension*, you can use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip):

```
[add(x, y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

`zip` takes *n* iterables, and generate *n*-tuples where the *i*-th tuple contains the *i*-th element of every iterable.

In case you want to add a default value to some parameters, you can use `partial` from `functools`. For instance if you define a:

```
def add (x, y, a, b):
    return x + y + a + b
```

```
from functools import partial

list(map(partial(add, a=3, b=4), list1, list2))
```

Here `x` and `y` are thus called as *unnamed* parameters, and `a` and `b` are by `partial` added as *named* parameters.

Or with list comprehension:

```
[add(x, y, 3, 4) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: ok, awesome. what if there were a couple other arguments that _didn't_ change. like `add(a, b, x, y)`, and you want to set `a = 3`, `b = 4`, and then iterate through the lists for x and y?

Comment: your edit answered my above Q. Also, it threw an error I think because of the comma you have after `add(x, y),`. Once I removed that it worked.

Comment: @MattW.: indeed, thanks for spotting it, removed it now :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! fixed my issue, and was a great explanation. I'll accept as soon as SO lets me. cheers